# How to achieve that design in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'd like to implement something like that (see the image) in Windows Phone. What's the best and easiest way to achieve that design?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYjGv.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack Panel in a Scroll viewer. That Stack Panel can then have n rows of horizontally oriented sub-Stack Panels, and each one of those can have a text block for each cell. You can try data binding as well. How many rows of data will be displayed?

Comment: i intend to bind it. because rows is depending on user choices. it can be 20 can be 100 can be 120, not more than that. how can i achieve that?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know all that much about data binding. There's a link here though that might be a good starting point (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207023%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).